# ACPI error while installing ubuntu, help

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, acpi

I'm trying to install LTS ubuntu on a secondary drive, the drive had ubuntu before but I formatted it a few months ago but now that I try reinstalling its giving me this ACPI error.

I tried installing ubuntu from a bootable usb using rufus in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVpNj.png) configuration

When installing ubuntu i selected default options for everything, except when asked what disk to install ubuntu to I selected to completely format the disk I was installing it on, the installation is fine until it asks me to restart where I get the code below.

```
6275256 ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve SB.PCIO.SATO.PRTO. GT
F.DSSP], AE NOT FOUND 20181213 /psargs-330)
6275264 ] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed SB.PCIO.SATO.PRTO. GT
F, AE NOT FOUND 20181213 /psparse-531)
6275613 ] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve [ SB.PCIO.SATO.PRT2. GT
F.DSSP], AE NOT FOUND 20181213 /psargs-930)
6275621 ] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed SB.PCIO.SATO.PRT2. GT
F, AE NOT FOUND 20161213 /psparse-531)
6275878 ] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve _SB.PCIO.SATO.PRTO.GT
F.DSSP), AE NOT FOUND 20181213 /psargs-330)
t 6275886 ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed SB.PCIO.SATO.PRTO.GT
F, AE NOT FOUND 20181213 /psparse-531)
6275986 ] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve _SB.PCIO.SATO.PRT1.GT
F.DSSP], AE NOT FOUND 20181213 /psargs-330)
6275991 ] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed SB.PCIO.SATO.PRT1.GT
F,AE NOT FOUND 20181213 /psparse-531)
6276056 ] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve _SB.PICO.SATO.PRT3._GT
F.DSSP], AE NOT FOUND 20181213 /psargs-330)
6276065 ] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed SB.PICO.SATO.PRT3._GT
F, AE NOT FOUND 20181213 /psparse-531)
6277192 ] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve SB.PCIO.SATO.PRT2. GT
F.DSSP], AE NOT FOUND 20181213 /psarg-330)
[ 6277200 ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed SB.PCIO.SATO.PRT2.GT
F, AE NOT FOUND 20181213 /psparse-531)
```

When I try to boot into the drive I get [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcU2l.jpg). I read about the problem and most solutions ask to access a grub menu to disable ACPI or something similar but i cant access the drive Ubuntu is installed or i get the previous image. What can i do to fix this? Any help is appreciated.

**Pc specs:**

- MSI krait gaming 3x Motherboard
- Intel i5 6600k
- gtx 1080
- installing on an Adata 240 gb ssd
- samsung 970 evo running windows
- 2 tb storage hdd, 3    tb storage hdd, 1 tb storage ssd (total 5
  drives)

Comment: A few items to check... Find your current BIOS version with `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and go to the manufacturer's web site and look for a newer BIOS. Check for a firmware update for the ADATA SSD (and your Samsung SSD). Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll surely miss them.

Comment: Is your CPU overclocked, or memory XMP enabled in the BIOS?

Comment: Sorry for late response, @heynnema My bios was updated but i re flashed anyways, My cpu is overclocked but I'm at bios level so I doubt that applies outside my current Windows installation, This drive had ubuntu before but I'll update it. Also how am i to run these commands, can you run unix commands? using the trial option?

Comment: I chcked now and XMP is off.

Comment: You might try un-overclocking the CPU, as it would make a difference in both Windows and Ubuntu. You might also boot into Windows and check for firmware updates for the 2 SSD's. The `Samsung Magician` can be downloaded from the Samsung web site. The ACPI errors seem to be with the SATA ports.